# View an image available in ftp

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ftp

I am aware of uploading & downloading images from ftp. but I want to know if there are any ways to display an image in browser which is available in ftp but without downloading the image using MVC application

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but it's realy unsafe:

```
<img src="ftp://username:password@my_ftp_ip_address/Images/imagename.jpg"/>
```

I recommend to share your ftp folder in a virtual directory on IIS, like http://www.yoursite.com/images/imagename.jpg

See how here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308150